# Alpine JS changing images with interval with window.setInterval() function

Tags: javascript, setinterval, alpine.js

I am trying solve trivial task with Alpine JS and standard JS function setInterval.
So I am trying to build an image selector where images are going to be changed every second (1000ms).

Here is what I got:

```
<div x-data="imgFunc()">
        <h1 class="text-xl py-3">Chosing the picture</h1>

        <div class="w-1/2">
            <img x-show = "img === 'img1'" src="{{ asset('images/training/img1.jpg') }}" alt="Main Image">
            <img x-show = "img === 'img2'" src="{{ asset('images/training/img2.jpg') }}" alt="Main Image">
            <img x-show = "img === 'img3'" src="{{ asset('images/training/img3.jpg') }}" alt="Main Image">
        </div>

        <div>
            <ul class="flex">
                <li class="w-1/6 p-3" :class="{ 'border' : img==='img1' }"><img src=" {{ asset('images/training/img1.jpg') }} " alt="image1" @click = "startImg"></li>
                <li class="w-1/6 p-3" :class="{ 'border' : img==='img2' }"><img src=" {{ asset('images/training/img2.jpg') }} " alt="image2" @click = "img='img2'"></li>
                <li class="w-1/6 p-3" :class="{ 'border' : img==='img3' }"><img src=" {{ asset('images/training/img3.jpg') }} " alt="image3" @click = "img='img3'"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>



    </div>



<script>
    function imgFunc(){
            var i = 1;
            var img ='img'+i;
            return {
            i,
            img,
            startImg(){
                var myvar = window.setInterval(function(){
                    this.img = 'img'+this.i;
                    if(this.i<3){
                        this.i++;
                    }else{
                        this.i=1;
                    }    
                }, 1000);
            },
            changeImg() {
                this.img = 'img'+this.i;
                if(this.i<3){
                    this.i++;
                }else{
                    this.i=1;
                }                       
            }

        }
        
    }

</script>
```

When image#1 in list is clicked the images should start changing but it never happens. Why?

I also tried to pass the function name changeImg() in @click event and it worked perfectly, by pressing on one images were changing one by one.

I also tried to pass the function name changeImg() to setInerval() like this:

```
startImg(){
     var myvar = window.setInterval(this.changeImg, 1000);
},
```

Or like this:

```
startImg(){
     var myvar = window.setInterval(changeImg, 1000);
},
```

I tried to change "this" to "self"

```
<script>
    function imgFunc(){
            var i = 1;
            var img ='img'+i;
            var self=this;
            return {
            i,
            img,
            startImg(){
                var myvar = window.setInterval(function(){
                    self.img = 'img'+self.i;
                    if(self.i<3){
                        self.i++;
                    }else{
                        self.i=1;
                    }    
                }, 1000);
            },
            changeImg() {
                this.img = 'img'+this.i;
                if(this.i<3){
                    this.i++;
                }else{
                    this.i=1;
                }                       
            }

        }
        
    }

</script>
```

But nothing really works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is the use of `function` so the `this` inside of the function is not the Alpine.js `this`. The `this` inside of `imgFunc` is also not the Alpine.js `this` (quick explanation of this is that `imgFunc` runs before Alpine.js is initialised to generate the initial "state" so `this` is the window)

There are 2 ways to fix it, either use `this` but use an arrow function inside of the `setInterval`:

```html
<script>
    function imgFunc(){
            var i = 1;
            var img ='img'+i;
            return {
            i,
            img,
            startImg(){
                var myvar = window.setInterval(() => {
                    this.img = 'img'+this.i;
                    if(this.i<3){
                        this.i++;
                    }else{
                        this.i=1;
                    }    
                }, 1000);
            },
            changeImg() {
                this.img = 'img'+this.i;
                if(this.i<3){
                    this.i++;
                }else{
                    this.i=1;
                }                       
            }

        }
        
    }

</script>
```

Alternatively you can set the `self = this` in the startImg function

```html
<script>
    function imgFunc(){
            var i = 1;
            var img ='img'+i;
            return {
            i,
            img,
            startImg(){
                var self=this;
                var myvar = window.setInterval(function(){
                    self.img = 'img'+self.i;
                    if(self.i<3){
                        self.i++;
                    }else{
                        self.i=1;
                    }    
                }, 1000);
            },
            changeImg() {
                this.img = 'img'+this.i;
                if(this.i<3){
                    this.i++;
                }else{
                    this.i=1;
                }                       
            }

        }
        
    }

</script>
```

There's another way to do this which is to use `.bind` on the `setInterval` callback, but that's more verbose and complicated.

Comment: Many thanks!!! worked like a charm! I new that something is wrong with visibility but I couldn't figure out what exactly...

Answer (score 0):

As hugo mentioned the context of `this` does not resolve to the outer function so you need to use arrow function as it does not have a context.

I made few changes to use alpine.js for what is made for.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.0.1/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alpinejs/2.7.3/alpine.js"></script>
<div x-data="imgFunc()">
  <h1 class="text-xl py-3">Chosing the picture</h1>

  <div class="w-1/2">
    <img :src="currentImage" alt="Main Image">
  </div>

  <div>
    <ul class="flex">
      <template x-for='(image,index) in images'>
        <li class="w-1/6 p-3" :class="{'border': currentImage===image}">
          <img :src="image" alt="image1" @click="startImg(index)">
        </li>
      </template>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>



<script>
  function imgFunc() {
    return {
      currentImage: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/5549634/pexels-photo-5549634.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=200&w=400',
      images: [
        'https://images.pexels.com/photos/5549634/pexels-photo-5549634.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=200&w=400',
        'https://images.pexels.com/photos/5101387/pexels-photo-5101387.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260',
        'https://images.pexels.com/photos/2363832/pexels-photo-2363832.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260'
      ],
      startImg(index) {
        this.currentImage = this.images[index];

        if (index > 0)
          return;

        let i = 0;
        var myvar = setInterval(() => {
          i = (i >= this.images.length - 1) ? 0 : ++i;
          this.currentImage = this.images[i];
        }, 1000);
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I would rather use blade templates for the same purpose... But still many thanks for your attention to this question.